# ExpressJS res.render() error (JSON.stringify can't work on circular reference)

Tags: node.js, express

What's wrong here?

`res.render('/somepage', {user:req.session.user})`

It leads to

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

errors, (results in session element that has a circular user reference.)

```
exports.home =  function (req, res) {
    var entityFactory = new require('../lib/entity-factory.js').EntityFactory();
    entityFactory.get_job_task_lists({
        callback : function (err, job_task_lists) {
            res.render('home.jade', {
                        locals:{
                            title: 'Logged in.', 
                            user:req.session.user, // does not work
                            job_task_lists:job_task_lists || [] 
                        }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I added some logging in `node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js`

```
MemoryStore.prototype.set = function(sid, sess, fn){
  var self = this;
  process.nextTick(function(){

    console.log(sess); //this is giving the output listed

    self.sessions[sid] = JSON.stringify(sess);
...
```

This is what I expect the session to look like, in terms of structure:

```
{ lastAccess: 1330979534026,
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     httpOnly: true,
     _expires: Tue, 06 Mar 2012 00:32:14 GMT,
     originalMaxAge: 14399999 },
  user: // this is the object I added to the session
   { id: 1,
     username: 'admin',
     password: '8e3f8d3a98481a9073d2ab69f93ce73b',
     creation_date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 18:08:55 GMT } }
```

But here's what I find:

```
{ lastAccess: 1330979534079, // new session
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     httpOnly: true,
     _expires: Tue, 06 Mar 2012 00:32:14 GMT,
     originalMaxAge: 14399999 },
  user:  // but here it is again, except now it's a mashup,
         // containing members it shouldn't have, like locals,
         // and, well, everything but the first 4 properties
   { id: 1,
     username: 'admin',
     password: '8e3f8d3a98481a9073d2ab69f93ce73b',
     creation_date: '2012-03-05T18:08:55.701Z',
     locals: 
      { title: 'Logged in.',
        user: [Circular], //and now it's circular
        job_task_lists: [Object] },
     title: 'Logged in.',
     user: [Circular],
     job_task_lists: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], getById: [Function] ],
     attempts: [ '/home/dan/development/aqp/views/home.jade' ],
     scope: {},
     parentView: undefined,
     root: '/home/dan/development/aqp/views',
     defaultEngine: 'jade',
     settings: 
      { env: 'development',
        hints: true,
        views: '/home/dan/development/aqp/views',
        'view engine': 'jade' },
     app: 
      { stack: [Object],
        connections: 6,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _handle: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        cache: [Object],
        settings: [Object],
        redirects: {},
        isCallbacks: {},
        _locals: [Object],
        dynamicViewHelpers: {},
        errorHandlers: [],
        route: '/',
        routes: [Object],
        router: [Getter],
        __usedRouter: true },
     partial: [Function],
     hint: true,
     filename: '/home/dan/development/aqp/views/home.jade',
     layout: false,
     isPartial: true } }

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Array.0 (/home/dan/development/aqp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:77:31)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

See how the user object is nested?

- Note that this time I did not send values in explicitly with **'locals'** but it ended up in one (thats the source of the circular reference.

It looks like the session is being used to transfer objects to the view.

Here's my only middleware (it only reads from the session):

```
function requiresAuthentication(req, res, next){
    if (req.session.user){
        next();
    } else {
        next(new Error('Unauthorized. Please log in with a valid account.'))
    }
}
```

and the only time I modify the req.session is in this route:

```
app.post('/home', function (req,res,next) {
    var auth = require('./lib/authentication');
    auth.authenticate_user(req.body.user, function (user) {
        if (user){
            req.session.user = user;
            console.log('authenticated');
            res.redirect(req.body.redir || '/home');
            //next();
        } else {
            console.log('not authenticated');
            res.render('logins/new.jade', {title: 'Login Failed', redir:''})
        }
    });
});
```

I don't have much else going on in my application yet, as it's still quite young. I know I'm not mangling the session anywhere myself; I checked.

I did some more testing, and it appears this is only an issue when I then try to use the local variable on a page. For instance, here is my view home.jade

```
div(data-role="page")
    div(data-role="header")
        a(href='/logout', data-icon='delete', data-ajax="false") Log out
        h1= title
        a(href='/account', data-icon='info', data-ajax="false") Account

        != partial('user', user)


    each jtl in job_task_lists
        div(id=jtl.name, class = 'draggable_item', style='border:2px solid black;')
            #{jtl.name} - #{jtl.description} 
        a(data-icon='plus') 


    div(data-role="footer")
        h3 footer

script(src="/javascripts/home.js")
```

If I comment out the user partial, it renders, else I get this `Converting circular structure to JSON` issue.

**UPDATE**
So after hooking up eclipse and the v8 debugger, I have been stepping through the code and I know where the mashup of session and user objects is occurring,

in `node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/session.js`

utils.union ends up mashing the members of the user object into the session, causing the circular reference. I'm just not sure why (admittedly probably my code)

Comment: You already assigned req.session.user to "u" in that callback. Does simply passing user: u work for the render call, avoiding that extra reference?

Comment: No, that also leads to the circular reference problem. I'm assuming this is all because I'm just not comprehending some particular closure...

I dug into the session implementation inside connect - and console.log(sess) where it does the stringify - and what I get looks like a mashup of the session variables (I'll add to the question the structure I get)

Comment: It's being added to the session, with a reference to itself already in session...

Comment: @DanielNWerner I just did some tests and also looked inside ExpressJS code and there is no difference between explicitly using `locals` variable and not. And there is **NO** interaction between session and view rendering (unless explicitly coded by developer). Also you do not set session in the code you just showed us. So I don't understand why it changes? Do you use some strange, custom middleware? What is your version of ExpressJS?

Comment: Looks like you're focusing on the wrong part of your code. Your call to include req.session.user seems to be doing exactly what you want it to; that user inside the session must have already been mangled in some previously executed code. As freakish mentioned, maybe it's being done inadvertently by some other middleware?

Comment: @freakish - Yes I discovered after more testing that I must have had a bit of a 'red herring' looking at 'locals'. I edited the question to reflect that I got the same results either way.

Just now I updated the question with the middleware and session modifying code. Thanks for looking at this! All help is appreciated.

Comment: @freakish - ExpressJS version 2.5.8

Comment: @DanielNWerner Maybe there is a problem in user definition itself? What DB you use? What mapping? Also try upgradeing Express to 3.0 (current I believe). I can't recreate the error you are dealing with, so if this won't work, then I won't be able to help you. :( Sorry, mate.

Comment: @freakish sorry for the long explanation - turns out the bug only showed up when partials were used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a problem with session data being modified in a view.

After much digging, I found that it was a bug in the way partials are handled in 2.5.8. I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1039), and subsequently a [patch](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1043). (in case anyone needs this info at a future date) as npm is still serving up Express 2.5.8 AFAIK.

Thanks for your help @freakish and @Ryan

Comment: Good job. I don't know why I couldn't reproduce the error. I'm glad you managed to fix this!